# As a Power Bi global admin, how to get the list of workspaces used in the business?

Tags: powerbi

I am Power BI global admin.

But I can't see workspaces created by other users.

How can I get the list of all workspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of workspaces in the tenant is visible in the [Admin portal -> Workspaces](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/workspaces). They can be managed using the "AsAdmin" REST APIs, in this case [GetGroupsAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-groups-as-admin).